# how do I in d-languge find the last modified data in mongodb collection, filtered with find({"..." : ".. "} )

Tags: mongodb, d

I am coding in d-language and are trying to extract the last modified document from an array of documents, with D language (not in the console !!!! )
The query is like this:

```
Collection ct = mongo.web.cell;
auto cell = ct.find({"room": 4 }).sort( {'_id': -1 } ).limit(1);
```

and the errors given by dub is

```
source/app.d(166,58): Error: found : when expecting ; following statement
source/app.d(166,61): Error: found } when expecting ; following statement
source/app.d(166,62): Error: found ) instead of statement
```

When changes arrive to a room the cell data is inserted, not updated
I'm using Visual Studio Code, latest version

Any ideas?

Comment: `{"room": 4 }` is no valid syntax, if you want to pass an associative array you need to use `["room": 4 ]`

Comment: Thks but that didn't work either, got these errors instead:
source/app.d(170,54): Error: unterminated character constant
source/app.d(170,56): Error: found id when expecting ; following statement
source/app.d(170,58): Error: unterminated character constant
source/app.d(170,60): Error: found : when expecting ; following statement
source/app.d(170,63): Error: found } when expecting ; following statement
source/app.d(170,64): Error: found ) instead of statement

Comment: And if I reduce the line to just find(["room":4]); I get this error mondo.Collection.find(T = BsonObject)(in Query query = Query.init, in QueryFlags flags = QueryFlags.NONE, in ReadPrefs readPrefs = null)

Comment: At `'_id'`, you are using single quotes. Those are for single characters only. It looks like you are trying to convert some MongoDB code from another language, I suggest you look at the actual documentation of the library you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I infer that you are using `mondo`, if you read the documentation of the library and some of the code from [here](http://code.dlang.org/packages/mondo) and [here](https://github.com/2night/mondo/blob/master/source/bsond.d#L271), the following is what you need to do:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://yourhost");
Collection ct = mongo.web.cell;

auto q = new Query(); // create a new query object
q.conditions["room"] = 4; // specify the query condition

auto s = new BsonObject("_id", "-1"); // creat a new bson object
q.sorts(s.dup); // use sorts not sort

ct.find(q).each!writeln; // find the results
```

When you use sort, you'll use the std.algorithm.sorting not the sorting function of mondo.

hope it works

Comment: Hi Quarashi it seems to work all the way down to printing, there it starts complaining (running 3.0.6 mongodb):Error: no property 'each' for type 'Cursor!(BsonObject)'

Comment: from manual for 3.0 :
db.users.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { print( "user: " + myDoc.name ); } );
doesn't work either
I do know I get the mondo.Collection

Comment: @AndersS, `each` is a standard library iteration function, just import `std.algorithm` and you can use it, or you can return the result then use foreach.

Comment: @AndersS, if it works kindly check the answer as correct, thank you :D